# Unable to add/update config variables in heroku?

Tags: heroku

I keep getting an error when I'm trying to add config variables in heroku. This used to work, but now it doesn't work anymore. It just says: "**Item could not be updated: Unknown Error. Please contact support.**" Has anybody else experienced this? I also tried opening the dev console while trying to update the config variables, seems like a bunch of CORS related errors.

[image: Item could not be updated: Unknown Error. Please contact support.]
[image: CORS errors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using the CLI.

Here's an example:

```
heroku config:set MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE=config_var_value --app appname
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  I have resolved it by adding a chrome CORS plugin.  I turn that on and I am able to quiet down that CORS error.  It worked the past couple weeks.  But seems like now Im getting 503 error.  (Maybe my API key has expired... Im not quite sure on that.).

Comment: I suggest doing it via command line.